# issues on android 2.3 displaying german special characters

Tags: android

Problem to display charecters like Ü ü é ä when coming from JSON response to Android Text view OS 2.3 .

From JSON it is coming Properly but when we do setText(jsonObj.getString("key"));

its not displaying properly.

Working fine on OS 4.0 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new String(jsonObj.getString("key").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```